# Netbeans project wouldn't give output

Tags: java, netbeans-12

I am using netbeans 12 with jdk 17.
I built and ran the following project, it shows as

`org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`

But the output is not obtained, the code has no errors and this is the only file in the project.

Code:

```
public class Bookclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try{
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        int ch;
        do{
            System.out.println("1.Insert 2.Update 3.Delete 4.Display 5.Exit\nEnter your choice:");
            ch=in.nextInt();
            books b=new books();
            switch(ch){
                case 1:
                    b.insert();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    b.update();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    b.delete();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    b.display();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        }while(ch!=5);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @sorifiend its clearly mentioned that I have built and run the project. The issue seems to be something else.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");`? If you remove that line the code will work fine

Comment: @sorifiend It is a driver class to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your issue:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
```

It is throwing an exception and causing your code to move to the catch block, print the message and then exit. We don't know exactly what the error is because you hide the exception, but you are most likely getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`

Edit your catch block to show the full error message like so.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        System.out.println("It worked!");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you are getting a `ClassNotFoundException` then make sure that the class/driver is on your classpath (There are many existing answers on StackOverflow or the web about how to resolve this).